# Harvard style for bibitem and cite

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

Could you please help me, how to do harvard style citations (Author, year) while using non-sorted citations in \bibitem and \cite? I currently get just [1] from \cite and I am not able to change it by any advice I found here. Example:

\bibitem{Wooldridge} J. Wooldridge  (2009). Introductory econometrics. Mason, OH: South Western, Cengage Learning.

\cite shall give me (Wooldridge, 2009)

Is it even possible to do it somehow without sorting all bibitems into categories? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you tried loading the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear` and specifying `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`? If you do that, `\citep{wooldridge}` should give you `(Wooldridge, 2009)`. Incidentally, if you load the `natbib` package, do make sure you don't load the `cite` package as well.

Comment: Thank you Mico, I added \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} at the beginning, \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} into bibliography and \let\cite\citep into main text. I get an error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citation.

Comment: When switching from one bibliography style to another, it's often necessary to blow away all aux files and to rerun latex/bibtex/latex/latex from scratch. What happens if you take these additional steps?